# Prestashop Admin Tab - Where clausole does not work

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm writing a Tab for prestashop that lists the customers with the country of origin.
So far it's ok, but I would like to filter the query or table by country so I would like to add something like:
WHERE iso_code = 'IT'
Apparently prestashop will not let me, how could I do?
This is my code:

```
<?php
include_once(PS_ADMIN_DIR.'/../classes/AdminTab.php');
class AdminCustomersCountries extends AdminTab
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = 'customer';
        $this->className = 'Customer';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->edit = false;
        $this->view = true;
        $this->delete = false;
        $this->deleted = false;
        $this->requiredDatabase = true;

        $this->_select = '(SELECT cy.iso_code FROM ps_address AS addr, ps_country AS cy WHERE addr.id_customer=a.id_customer AND addr.id_country=cy.id_country) AS iso_code';
        $this->fieldsDisplay = array(
        'id_customer' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center', 'width' => 25),
        'lastname' => array('title' => $this->l('Last Name'), 'width' => 80),
        'firstname' => array('title' => $this->l('First name'), 'width' => 60),
        'email' => array('title' => $this->l('E-mail address'), 'width' => 120, 'maxlength' => 19),
        'active' => array('title' => $this->l('Enabled'), 'width' => 25, 'align' => 'center', 'active' => 'status', 'type' => 'bool', 'orderby' => false),
        'newsletter' => array('title' => $this->l('News.'), 'width' => 25, 'align' => 'center', 'type' => 'bool', 'callback' => 'printNewsIcon', 'orderby' => false),
        'iso_code' => array('title' => "Nazione", 'width' => 60, 'orderby'=>false, 'search'=>false));

        $this->optionTitle = "Prova";
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function postProcess()
    {
        // This function is executed when the Submit button is clicked
        // Use it to store the value of text fields in the database

        parent::postProcess();
    }

    public function displayForm($token=NULL)
    {
        // This function can be used to create a form with text fields
    }
}

?>
```

Here, however, I try to add the WHERE clause, with no results:

```
<?php
include_once(PS_ADMIN_DIR.'/../classes/AdminTab.php');
class AdminCustomersCountries extends AdminTab
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->table = 'customer';
        $this->className = 'Customer';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->edit = false;
        $this->view = true;
        $this->delete = false;
        $this->deleted = false;
        $this->requiredDatabase = true;

        $this->_select = '(SELECT cy.iso_code FROM ps_address AS addr, ps_country AS cy WHERE addr.id_customer=a.id_customer AND addr.id_country=cy.id_country AND cy.iso_code='IT') AS iso_code';
        $this->fieldsDisplay = array(
        'id_customer' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center', 'width' => 25),
        'lastname' => array('title' => $this->l('Last Name'), 'width' => 80),
        'firstname' => array('title' => $this->l('First name'), 'width' => 60),
        'email' => array('title' => $this->l('E-mail address'), 'width' => 120, 'maxlength' => 19),
        'active' => array('title' => $this->l('Enabled'), 'width' => 25, 'align' => 'center', 'active' => 'status', 'type' => 'bool', 'orderby' => false),
        'newsletter' => array('title' => $this->l('News.'), 'width' => 25, 'align' => 'center', 'type' => 'bool', 'callback' => 'printNewsIcon', 'orderby' => false),
        'iso_code' => array('title' => "Nazione", 'width' => 60, 'orderby'=>false, 'search'=>false));

        $this->optionTitle = "Prova";
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function postProcess()
    {
        // This function is executed when the Submit button is clicked
        // Use it to store the value of text fields in the database

        parent::postProcess();
    }

    public function displayForm($token=NULL)
    {
        // This function can be used to create a form with text fields
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using a sub query there , but there are two other options the PS AdminTab class provides.

1) Where : Whenever you need an addition where clause, you can write it like below

```
$this->_where = 'your condition here';
```

2) Joins : PS also provides the additional joins feature for you and you can write them like

```
$this->_join = 'write down all your joins here like normal queries';
```

Now if you want to get additional infos from other tables with additional checks (wheres), then you can do it as followed. :

**Note : For tables, PS give an alias start with "a" and if it has additional tables like language tables, then it goes with b and so on. So you should know that and in join, _select and in _where you should use the correct aliases.  **

```
$this->_select = 'all your additional fields from the tables you need. Those tables should be joined in the _join query.';

$this->_join = 'All your joins here with correct aliases, as these aliases are used in _select query and in _where';

$this->_where = 'your where clauses here.';
```

I hope this will help you to correct your query.

Thank you

Comment: I can use a custom query instead of prestashop subquery? How I can do this? Where I can find a documentation for prestashop tabs query??

Comment: Are you supposed to write the keyword 'WHERE'. I ask because I'm doing the same thing but getting an error: Bad SQL Query. I added this line: `$this->_where = 'a.id_customer!=0 ';` and also tried `$this->_where = 'WHERE a.id_customer!=0 ';`. Both don't work

Comment: Share the full error message, so i can see the sql query

Answer (score 0):

The line `$this->_select = '(SELECT cy.iso_code FROM ps_address AS addr, ps_country AS cy WHERE addr.id_customer=a.id_customer AND addr.id_country=cy.id_country AND cy.iso_code='IT') AS iso_code';` searches for IT using `'IT'`.

PHP will not read the IT because the apostrophes are not escaped. I think using `AND cy.iso_code=\'IT\')` should work.

Comment: I'm Sorry,but it was a writing error when I've edited the second code posted. However I've tryed with cy.iso_code=\'IT\' and it does not work..

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it's `SELECT cy.iso_code FROM ps_address`. As far as I can tell you're requesting the iso_code from the wrong table.

Comment: Uhm no, the system show me all the table with all data (including iso_code), I need only a filter with a WHERE clause or with a prestashop function

Comment: The query generated by Prestashop is this:
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
   
   a.*, (SELECT a cy.iso_code FROM ps_address AS addr, ps_country AS cy WHERE addr.id_customer=a.id_customer AND addr.id_country=cy.id_country AND cy.iso_code='IT') AS iso_code 
   FROM `ps_customer` a
   
   
   WHERE 1
   
   
   ORDER BY a.`id_customer` ASC
   LIMIT 0,50